# A plotly plot with many points is very heavy and cannot unzoom

Tags: python, plotly

I have made a plot with plotly. It has five plots in it, each with 25409 points.

My problem is that the plot appears but it is very heavy when I try to zoom it and unzoom it is impossible.

Is there a way that I can do this in a more practical way?

Each plot is like this

```
hover_text1 = dff.apply(lambda row: f'({row["x"]},{row["y"]}) at {row["f"]}', axis=1)

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df.x, y= df.y, mode='lines+markers', text=hover_text1, name='left', line=dict(color='orange',width=linewidth),marker=dict(symbol='circle', size=markersize),hoverinfo='text'))
```

EDIT:
I tried using plotly-resampler but it did not work because it required my data to be monotonically increasing.

I was suggested to sort the data. This presents the following problems:

1. My data has five plots. Each plot is data from different fields of the dataframe. I guess I would have to sort it every time I add a plot?
2. Even with only one plot, it did not work

My plot (well a zoom of it) must look like this

[image]

however when I sort it by x I get

[image]

and I don't know why

Answer (score 3):

I would look into the [plotly-resampler library](https://github.com/predict-idlab/plotly-resampler). The basic idea is that depending on how far you are zoomed in, the data is downsampled so that you're loading less data.

Comment: Thanks! I have just found that too. It seems it runs on Dash so it cant be saved as html. But anyway I think it might help me. I run an example and although not perfect (could not unzoom it either) it seems good. I ll post if it helped me later

Comment: mmm it did not work. I got the error: AssertionError: In order to perform time series aggregation, the data must be sorted in time; i.e., the x-data must be (non-strictly) monotonically increasing. I will try to make a minimum example to ask another question here

Comment: @KansaiRobot what happens if you sort the data by `x` which i am assuming is a date or datetime? Try `df = df.sort_values(by=['x'])`

Comment: I tried, but it did not work as expected. I explained in the question edit

Comment: @KansaiRobot can you provide some sample data so we can try to reproduce the behavior you're seeing? you can copy and paste the output from `df.head(10).to_dict()` directly into your question – thanks